# Python CV Webcam - Null Argument To Internal Routine

Tags: python, computer-vision

having recently learned the basics of python, I thought I would dive in with a small project to build on.
A webcam application. I would then add tools as I developed my skills.

I have installed matplotlib, CV, numpy, and various others,the code I found:

```
import cv

cv.namedWindow("lll")
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
while( cap.isOpened() ) :
    ret,img = cap.read()
    cv.imshow("lll",img)
    k = cv.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
 break
```

Now the initial "video Source" dialogue comes up, I select my webcam and press OK.
Then I get an error:

while(cap.isOpened()):
SystemError: null argument to internal routine

Done a bit of googling. Found others with the same issue but no resolution...
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not addressing your specific problem, but you can always use the newer `cv2` module:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("lll")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("lll",img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Yeaa I had a nightmare installing CV2. In fact I'm still trying now

Comment: I see, I hope you get a newer version because CV2 is much easier to work with. Btw, on my 2.4 version your original code gives me ``AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'namedWindow'``.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that would require digging into the source of PyCV (or whatever the interface to OpenCV is called) to fix. My tip to you would be to go to the OpenCV IRC-channel and ask or/and file a bug report.